# Add #gallery on back of the URL - for ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby script for a photo with a link to its url:

```
<%= if property.images[0] then link_to image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('350x263', :jpg)), user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], :property_id => property) end -%>
```

How do I append `#gallery` to the end of the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (broken into multiple lines for clarity):

```
link_to(
  image_tag(property.images[0].image.url('350x263', :jpg)),
  user_property_image_path(user,
    :id => property.images[0],
    :property_id => property,
    :anchor => "gallery"
  )
)
```

The key bit is `:anchor => "gallery"`. `#url_for` will recognize this and append it to the URL as a URL fragment.

See the [documentation on url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) for a full list of available options.

Comment: I just try what you show, but got a error when try to load this page:<%= if property.images[0] then 
link_to (

image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('350x263', :jpg)), 
user_property_image_path(user, 
:id => property.images[0], 
:property_id => property,
:anchor => "gallery"
          )
) 

end -%>